# Что читать про ООП в плане проектирования, идеологии, парадигмы?

Tags: ооп, c++

Не понимаю, как выявлять классы при разработке программы. Что еще хуже, никак не могу понять, как классы должны взаимодействовать между собой и что классы должны делать. Хоть ООП взято из нашей жизни, все равно как-то ничего не очевидно. Ну взять ключевые слова из описании будущей программы - это еще можно, выяснить поведение, как по шагам работает программа, но толку нет, потому что не могу понять, как классы должны взаимодействовать между собой и что классы должны делать.

Comment: как все сложно... ну и вопросы... смотри примеры, каждый класс - это отображение идеи, их поведение и взаимодействие - это реализация. Пример , класс яблоко - свойства зеленое, класс - корзина, свойство - плетеная, взаимодействие - корзина хранит яблока, может добавлять и удалять их из себя.

Comment: Хм, а что же вы вообще про это прочитали, и где там непонятное нашли ? :\

Comment: И как всегда все приводят простые аналогии, а на деле...
Вот пример: Игра тетрис. Какие классы? Тетрис, стакан(игровое поле), тетрамино(разные виды и цвета). Даже в этом у меня не получается понять. Тетрамино должно само крутится? Кто обрабатывает очки? Стакан или тетрис? Пусть тетрамино это матрица, в которой "нарисована" нолями и единицами фигурка. Я эту матрицу должен посылать стакану, а он в свою очередь ее обрабатывать или как? И т.д. Может для вас просто, а у меня опыта нет. Я не знаю как найти исходники программ не сложных и не простых, где можно было бы увидеть хорошие реализации с ОО

Comment: lirik90, читал книгу по С++, где был пример с проектированием и реализации простой "учебной" системы для банкомата. В общем-то и спрашиваю что почитать, но чтобы подробнее и примеров больше.

Comment: ну надо отдельный класс фигуры - это один объект, они куда-то там складываются - это другой, если они уже где-то лежат, там их можно и обрабатывать, если надо, что бы они сами крутились - это их свойство, если что бы кто-то крутил - это его =). Начни, что то делать, покажи код и тогда тебе помогут быстрее..

Comment: Я один раз попытался  расписать на словах проектирование тетриса(выявление классов и что они будут делать), так и никто не ответил. Правда писал в разделе для новичком по С++ на одном форуме. Наверно надо попробовать написать на англ. форумах, где много народу.

Comment: @Barmaley "Хоть ООП взято из нашей жизни" -- кто же с Вашей жизнью такое сотворил-то? Когда-то я считал, что если при решении обычных задач ООП создаёт проблемы, то уж в имитационном-то моделировании это то, что доктор прописал. Позже прочитал, что насчёт моделирования я был сильно не прав.

Comment: @alexlz, когда то поймешь, ооп - это взгляд на все вещи как на обьекты, со своими свойствами. Этого не видно в веб программировании и не видно в функциональном, и если правильно пользоватся основными принципами ооп, то все будет хорошо и понятное дело, что тривиальные задачки лучше немешать с обьектами

Comment: @Gorets из школьного курса литературы:

    Только вот жить в эту пору прекрасную
    Уж не придётся ни мне, ни тебе.

PS: OOP и OOD -- разные аббревиатуры.

Comment: @alexlz а я то тут причем?!

Comment: @Barmaley это такой тонкий тролинг :)

Comment: @Barmaley цитату из вопроса я привёл. Ну а в качестве ответа: http://www.paulgraham.com/noop.html Ну и обсужение/флейм по поводу этого эссе. Там (в обсуждениях) много забавного.

Ну ещё тут советуют Буча. Вот ссылка на одного серба, который советует Мартина: http://www.jelovic.com/misc/people.htm


     "Previous editor of the C++ Report. Teaches good object-oriented design and doesn't sell you any bullshit, unlike Grady Booch."

Comment: @alexlz - намек понял и ответил - см. ниже :)

Comment: @alexlz дак топикстартер другой, Barmaley лишь редактировал сообщение

Comment: @rasmisha позор на мои седины...

Comment: Значит у тебя иммунитет к заболеванию "ООП головного мозга".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте написать пару классов совсем простых, состоящих из пары методов и попытайтесь связать их, как уже сказали выше. Не нужно сразу поднимать неподсильную нишу перечитывая тонны теории и 0 практики. Лучше делать то и то постепенно, нежели наоборот.

Answer (score 7):

Если вам тяжело проектировать сверху, то один раз попробуйте писать программу снизу в китайском стиле вообще не объявляя классы и  функции, оставив только переменные, математические выражения и встроенные библиотеки языка. Как только она увеличиться в размерах так что вы уже не сможете нормально дебагать начинайте объединять повторяющиеся участки кода в функции.  Увидели повторяющиеся пачки переменных объединяйте их в структуры. Как только осознали что одни и те же функции применяются к одним и тем же структурам самое время объявить класс. ПроЭкт разросся до такой степени что есть несколько классов похожих друг на друга? Стоит серьезно подумать о наследовании, полиморфизме и отделении интерфейсов от реализации. Проект стал просто огромных размеров? Самое время выпустить STL алгоритмы не зависящие от типов данных. Разработка итеративный процесс и если вам хватит терпения вы все равно рано или поздно придете к нужной иерархии классов. Далеко не факт что она совпадет с той что вы предполагали в самом начале. Для того чтобы сразу обеспечить такое совпадение нужен огромный опыт проектирования.

Например тот вариант с тетрисом что вам предложили в комментариях это хороший пример ООП оверинжиниринга и неправильного проектирования. Всю эту игру при должной сноровке можно свести к одномерному байтовому массиву хранящему игровое поле и десятком функций над ним вообще не объявив ни одного класса. Генерации нужной фигурки, удаление  полных строчек, опускание всей картинки на одну клетку вниз, вращение фигурки(при этом фигурка это не отдельный класс, а просто 4 байта в массиве), определение столкновения фигурки с основной конструкцией и.т.д.

Comment: и запихнуть все это в один класс под названием "bitcrushing_premature_optimized_tetris". Получился бы подлинный шедевр.

Comment: Видимо @Yura Ivanov свой комментарий о маленьком стакане удалил. Так что ответный комментарий от @igumnov как-то повис...

Comment: В качестве полезного комментария хотел бы ответить, что в реальной жизни вопрос оверинжиниринга во многих случаях является "заделом на будущее". Редко какой проект завершается на первой версии и вопрос расширяемости встает очень остро при планировании бюджета для второй версии. То, что можно сделать одной гениальной процедурой, пренебрегая каким-либо принципами (не только ооп, но и в процедурном программинге), отказываясь от удобства по причине "громоздкости" структур ведет в итоге к переписыванию всего проекта с нуля. То же будет с примером про тетрис, с вероятностью 1.

Comment: Если путь от китайчины до идеала может быть полезен на этапе обучения профессии, то во взрослой жизни такой роскоши не будет.

Comment: Да это верно, поддерживаю. Нужно быть крайне осторожным в таких вещах если проект действительно больших размеров и над ним работает несколько человек. Но ТС видимо еще не слишком искушен в этих вопросах, поэтому я и предложил "китайский" вариант. Хотя можно конечно и пытаться декомпозировать на объекты совсем простые задачи.

Comment: Похоже обсуждение этого вопроса показало, что *действительно трудно* придумать *небольшую задачку* при решении которой использование ООП не было бы "притянуто за уши".

Answer (score 5):

Мой ответ будет весьма неожиданным. Чтобы научиться проектировать классы и их взаимодействие, нужно изучать философию. Разумеется, готовых рецептов она в себе не содержит, но зато учит мыслить в нужном ключе. Проектирование классов требует развитого абстрактного мышления, умения отличать существенные признаки объекта от несущественных, умения выявлять общие свойства у целого множества классов. Философия занимается именно этим. Только предметом её исследований выступают объекты реального мира и то, как они взаимодействуют друг с другом.

Ну, или можно пойти простым путём. Есть очень практичное правило, которое помогает в 99% случаев. Дело в том, что абстрактное мышление тесно связано с языком. Очень тесно. Фактически, когда человек думает, он думает на каком-то языке (опытные программисты думают сразу на С++). Поэтому философия очень тесно связана с лингвистикой. И это можно использовать следующим образом. Правило очень простое: если удалось придумать для класса простое название, которое полностью отражает его суть, то значит класс спроектирован более-менее удачно. Разумеется, при добавлении в класс чего-то нового нужно следить за тем, чтобы название по-прежнему соответствовало. Трюк основан на том, что в языке, который развивался столетиями, уже есть удобные названия для всех необходимых абстракций. Если же название подобрать не удаётся, то значит с классом что-то не так.

Comment: Интересные мысли. 

--

А по моему, философия тесно связана с лингвистикой лишь потому, что она не производит ничего нового. 

На самом деле новые вещи (мысли) сначала невербальны, они возникают в виде неких зрительных образов (часто динамических, меняющихся). Затем, безусловно, эти образы и процесс их трансформации описывается словами, т.е. комбинацией уже существующих (и ставших вербальными) понятий. В противном случае это новое останется только в голове изобретателя.

--

Конечно, для практического программирования (... в комменте мало места ...) трюк с именами выглядит разумным.

Comment: Здравый смысл подсказывает, что так оно и должно быть. Кажется, что любая мысль сначала появляется в голове, и только потом происходит её перевод на язык. К сожалению, в данном случае здравый смысл даёт осечку. Выражение какой-то мысли на языке - это не просто перевод с языка мыслей на язык понятий. Никакого языка мыслей просто нет. И люди просто не могут думать такие мысли, которые нельзя выразить на известном им языке. Этот вопрос очень хорошо исследован. У людей с ограниченным словарным запасом нет проблем с тем, как выразить свои сложные мысли. В их головах сложные мысли не зарождаются.

Comment: Возможна и другая гипотеза по поводу:

    Никакого языка мыслей просто нет. И люди просто не могут думать такие мысли, которые нельзя выразить на известном им языке. Этот вопрос очень хорошо исследован.

просто все мы разные, а исследователи, занимающиеся этой темой устроены так, как они это описывают.

Comment: Вот это очень верная мысль. Действительно, все мы разные, и поэтому язык мыслей не может существовать. Ведь язык - это инструмент взаимодействия. Грубо говоря, это аналог интерфейса для взаимодействия с разными объектами, имеющими нечто общее. Но мы настолько разные, что мысли двух людей не могут быть сведены к общему интерфейсу. Да в этом и нет никакой необходимости. По крайней мере, до тех пор, пока люди не эволюционировали в телепатов.

Comment: @Shamov "опытные программисты думают сразу на С++". Даже опытные программисты на паскале?

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сказал так по-поводу проектирования. Это в общем-то на 90% искусство, здесь или дано или нет.

Возьмите для примера проектирование архитектуры игры в "крестики-нолики". Если вы не в состоянии ничего придумать - значит вам не дано. Если в течение часа родите жизнеспособную конструкцию (пусть неидеальную) то значит дано. Дальше можно читать умные книжки или например [такой набор статей](http://www.objectmentor.com/omSolutions/oops_what.html), в общем нарабатывать опыт и проч.

Comment: А что программировать в крестиках-ноликах? Там будет функция main и максимум две функции. В одной проверка победил ли кто, в другой можно перерисовывать игровое поле. И насчет искусства, может ли человек стать великим музыкантом, не умея пользоваться музыкальным инструментом? А у меня можно сказать почти нет опыта в ООП.

Comment: @chevchelios Классы какие будут в крестиках-ноликах?

P.S. Проектировать программу это как писать музыку. Согласитесь, даже умея играть на инструментах не все умеют писать музыку.

Answer (score 2):

Ничего не понятно.  Если вам нужно понимание синтаксиса ООП, то читать Лафоре Р. "Объектно-ориентированное программирование в C++" или лучше Страуструпа.

Если вам нужно понимание "проектирования, идеологии, парадигмы", то рекомендую изучать это на книге "Философия Java" Брюс Эккель.

Comment: Синтаксис я знаю. Но знать синтаксис не значит знать ООП.

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: А синтаксис ООП -- это синтаксис С++ или синтаксис Smalltalk? (Чисто исторически это может быть синтаксис Simula 67, т.е. расширенный синтаксис Алгола-60)

Comment: Синтаксис C++

Comment: А. А то можно ещё вспомнить closures из лиспа/схемы, которые можно рассматривать, как объектно-ориентированное программирование наизнанку...

Comment: Не понял, что вы хотите этим сказать.

Answer (score 2):

Советую почитать книгу "Объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование" Гради Буча. Написано немного тяжелым языком, но отлично помогает понять парадигму ООП.

Answer (score 2):

[[@chevchelios](/users/8262/chevchelios)](/users/8262/chevchelios), не переживай! Я тоже в самом начале своего пути не понимал смысла ООП( да не я один, думаю...). Однажды мне пришлось решить задачу, которую без ООП решить можно было костыльно, как я собственно и поступил. Долго ломал голову над задачей, пока один мой знакомый не предложил мне использовать ООП. "Не вижу в этом смысла!" - сказал я, но "тот самый Знакомый" показал мне, ка это можно легко решить задачу с использованием ООП. Его код выглядел куда более изящнее и короче моего, работал в любых случаях, в отличие от моего =) Долго копаясь в его коде и разбирая все, что мне было не понятно, я вдруг ахнул, и осознал всю мощь ОО-программирования! Мораль сей басни такова: Не спешите, ждите подходящего момента для изучения, и все, что вам необходимо, само "залезет" в голову. Все познается на практике.

Answer (score 1):

У Microsoft есть бесплатная книга для маленьких по C#, там очень не плохо описано ООП. Далеко от идеала, но все же.

Еще порекомендую CLR via C# 3е издание автор Джеффри Рихтер.
Это не совсем по ООП, но про язык сам по себе объектно ориентированный. Некоторая часть того что я знаю про ООП сейчас была получена из этой книги. Если планируете связываться с C#, рекомендую сразу ее и читать.

Answer (score 1):

Читай именно Бьерна Страуструпа "The C++ Programming Language" ("Язык программирования С++") и, если затянет, советую его другую книгу "Дизайн и эволюция С++". Почему его? Да потому, что он принимал активное участие в создании стандарта ANSI/ISO для C++, книга имеет множество наград и написана доступным языком.